# Hiding each clicked button

Tags: jquery, click

I have a form with many buttons arranged in grid layout to look like calculator buttons, i want to hide each button that is clicked using Jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() 
  {

    var my_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button'); // get all button elements on the page

    for(var i=0; i<my_buttons.length; i++)
      {

        if(my_buttons[i].clicked == true) my_buttons.hide();
      }

    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"that is clicked"_?

Comment: $('button').click(function() { $(this).hide(); });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) to detect when the button is clicked, and [`.hide`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) to hide the button.

I used `$(this)` to hide the button you just clicked.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
```

Comment: Yeah!!..thank you. I Edited $(".btn") to $("button")

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".buttonClass").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Put a general class name for all buttons and use it as selector. Or you can use jquery element selector like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```